# Is there a way of creating a striped css left-border within a textfield

Tags: css

I am trying to change this red border left colour into a stripped colour. Similar to this below. However within the borderLeftColor property I cannot achieve this effect.

[image]

[image]

Here is my current code

```
     <TextField
          name="title"
          label="Enter Something"
          id="title"
          variant="outlined"
          className={styles.banner}
        />

  banner: {
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
      borderLeftColor: 'red',
      borderLeftWidth: '6px',
    },
  },
```

Comment: Can you use a background image instead of borders?

Answer (score 0):

use a background

```css
input {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg,red 0 5px, white 0 10px,blue 0 15px,white 0 20px) left/10px 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```